# How to change error format of all errors using Connexion + Tornado

Tags: python, flask, error-handling, connexion

I'm using Connexion (https://github.com/zalando/connexion) to make sure my openapi-specification is well-followed and to have easy integration points to connect my routes to the underlying functions.

In any case, the default error responses from Connexion are json responses following the  [Problem Details for HTTP APIs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-http-problem-00) RFC. That is the following format, e.g.:

```
{
    "detail": "None is not of type 'object'",
    "status": 404,
    "title": "BadRequest",
    "type": "about:blank"
}
```

However, I would like to change the format of all errors sent to something like:

```
{
    error: {
        code: 400,
        message: 'BadRequest',
        detail: 'ID unknown'
        innererror: {...}
    }
}
```

I can not find any way to intercept **every** error to change the format of what is returned. I know I can extend the `connection.exception.ProblemException` class and add a dict to the `ext`parameter in its constructor, but for any `400` error for example, I can't intercept it.

So, I know that it is possible to add error handlers for specific error codes, e.g.:

```
app.add_error_handler(404, error.normalize)
app.add_error_handler(400, error.normalize)
```

However, for the `404` handler I manage to successfully intercept the error. But for the `400` (e.g. a json validation error) - the interception does not work.

How can I intercept each and every error that is sent from Connexion and change the json format, even if it is just to extend it like:

```
{
    "detail": "Could not find page",
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Could not find requested document."
    },
    "status": 404,
    "title": "NotFound",
    "type": "about:blank"
}
```

I use Connexion, with a 'tornado' server.

Thanks in advance.
Tom

Answer (score 3):

With the latest version (connexion==2.5.1) this works for me:

```
from connexion import ProblemException
[...]

connexion_app.add_error_handler(400, render_http_exception)
connexion_app.add_error_handler(404, render_http_exception)
connexion_app.add_error_handler(ProblemException, render_problem_exception)
```

My exception handling functions:

```
from flask import jsonify


def render_http_exception(error):

    resp = {
        'error': {
            'status': error.name,
            'code': error.code,
            'message': error.description,
        }
    }

    return jsonify(resp), error.code


def render_problem_exception(error):

    resp = {
        'error': {
            'status': error.title,
            'code': error.status,
            'message': error.detail,
        }
    }

    return jsonify(resp), error.status
```

You can easily change it to your format.